# Hairy black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, hawking-radiation, no-hair-theorem

I was wondering why it is said that if a black hole has hair we can measure its charge at infinity, where does this statement come from?
It doesn't seem right to me because solutions to KG equation are usually $\sim 1/r$, thus $0$ at infinity.

In addition is there any physical quantity to measure it?

Comment: Who says we can measure the hair carried by the black hole?

Comment: there are hairs that we can measure, you can look for hairy black hole theories and find many of them

Comment: It seems that I cannot understand the question. This is part of the definiton of a hair. There is no conserved quantity associated to a Gauss-like form with it (like the mass, angular momentum and electromagnetic charge). How can we measure such a thing?

Comment: Everything is 0 at infinity, even the force excerted by a normal particle which is not a black hole. That is not what we mean by the mass or charge measured at infinity, but for example that GM/√[r³(r-rs)] reduces to GM/r² if r is much larger than rs. That's how Einstein found out that one of the constants in his equations was the mass, by checking the Newtonian limit at infinity.

Comment: The other question *"where does this statement come from?"* can only be answered by yourself, since you didn't provide a direct quote or link to where you got that from. If you google the topic first thing you will find is that a black hole has mass, charge and spin, and all the other stuff that can't be observed is called hair, so I have no idea how you conclude *"if a black hole has hair we can measure its charge at infinity"*, since for that we don't need any extra hair.